# Java date formatting for SQL

Tags: java, sql, date

I have a date object I constructed with:

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(2013, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    Date begin = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

I am trying to use it in a query and I know the query takes the format like: `2008-10-29 14:56:59`

When I print my date it looks like: `Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2014`

**My question:**

How do I convert the date format from `Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2014` to `2008-10-29 14:56:59`

Comment: Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, was just reading it. So would `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` do the trick?

Comment: Yes, it will convert the date into the format you want.

Comment: you want to format the date String to use it directly in a SQL statement ? Why not use JPA to do the Object - Relational mapping for you ? Anyway I guess the date String format will depend on the underlying DB you're using.

Comment: @guilhebl Or use a `java.sql.Timestamp` with JDBC directly.

Comment: what @MarkRotteveel said. Regardless of your interface to JDBC, you should be binding variables to fixed sql statements, not concatenating strings - otherwise you're just asking for a sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I converted to a `timestamp` and used that but I am still returning a bunch of data that is not within my range. Shouldn't `s.time > :begin AND s.time < :end` return the data between those timestamps?

Comment: @JordanD - yes, it should. If you are getting data that's close to the range, but off by an hour or a few hours, it may be a timezone difference. If it's off by days or more, then you need to take a closer look at the data that's actually in the database and your query.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I tested the same query in mysql workbench and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(2013, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateFormat dateFormat;
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis())));
```

- 11 is DECEMBER

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment about December.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the format you want

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String dateInString = "pass you date string here";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simpleDateFormat class. I given simple example below.

Here you have to provide your required date format, Date object.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String date =null;    
date = dateformat.format(begin);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use objects rather than strings when communicating with your database. For a date-time value, use a date-time object.

## java.time

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes including `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`. They are poorly-designed, flawed, and confusing. Among their troubles is `toString` methods that dynamically apply the JVM’s current default time zone when generating a string, meant to be helpful but turns out to be an anti-feature.

Instead, use the modern java.time classes.

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is updated for [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html) and [later](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr221/JDBC4.3MR-January2017.pdf), use the java.time types directly rather than the java.sql types.

Alter your input string to comply with ISO 8601 format. Change that SPACE in middle to `T`.

```
String input = "2008-10-29 14:56:59".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` since your input lacks any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Or specify the date-time value as integers.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2013 , 12 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;
```

If your database column is of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, you are ready to query. Be sure you understand that without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, such values do *not* represent a specific moment, and are *not* a point on the timeline, rather they are vague ideas about possible moments.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ WHERE when_ >= ? ; " ; 
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
ps.setObject( 1 , ldt ) ;  // Call `setObject` to pass a java.time object directly without converting into `java.sql.*` type.
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery() ;
…
LocalDateTime ldt = resultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

If you had intended to track actual moments, specific points on the timeline, then you would be using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as your database column type, and using `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` java.time classes.